# Get specific info on domain computers from AD OUs

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to Get the Name, Manufacturer, and model of computers so i can distinguish what computers are out of warranty in AD.

I'm trying to do this by getting the computer names and putting there info into the corresponding .csv file but this fails and puts 1 ou to multiple .csv files and then moves to the second ou and does the same thing?

```
$myMultiArray = @(("OU=Domain Controllers,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM"), 
("OU=Computers,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM"))
$myFileArray = @(("‪D:\VS-Code\Powershell\AD_Computer_Management\OUs\Domain 
Controllers.csv"),("‪D:\VS- 
Code\Powershell\AD_Computer_Management\OUs\Computers.csv"))


foreach ($MultiOU in $myMultiArray) {

    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $MultiOU -SearchScope 2 | Select-object Name | Out-File -FilePath "D:\VS-Code\Powershell\AD_Computer_Management\OUs\garbage.csv"

    For ($i = 0; $i – $myFileArray.Length - 1; $i++) {
            Write-Host $myMultiArray[$i]

            [string[]]$cnArray = Get-Content -Path 'D:\VS-Code\Powershell\AD_Computer_Management\OUs\garbage.csv'

            Write-Host $OU
            if ($i -eq $i) {
                    foreach($CN in $cnArray){
                    Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $OU | Format-List -Property Name, Manufacturer, Model | Out-File -FilePath $myFileArray[$1]
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

I've tried multiple variations of different loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things:

> Out-File -FilePath $myFileArray[$1]

Should be:

```
Out-File -FilePath $myFileArray[$i]
```

And also you might need to append:

```
Out-File -FilePath $myFileArray[$i] -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code, like `$i – $myFileArray.Length`, which  should be `$i –lt $myFileArray.Length`.
Then there is `Out-File -FilePath $myFileArray[$1]` as [Bernard Moeskops](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9304296/bernard-moeskops) already mentioned.
Also your code seems to want to create both the `Domain Controllers.csv` aswell as the `Computers.csv` files regardless of the OU you are currently in.

Lastly, you are using `Out-File` to create the CSV files where for proper CSV output, you should use the [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

The following code should do what you want:

```
$myOUArray  = "OU=Domain Controllers,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM", "OU=Computers,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM"
$myFilePath = "‪D:\VS-Code\Powershell\AD_Computer_Management\OUs"  # just the path for the output files is needed

foreach ($OU in $myOUArray) {
    # determine the file name from the OU we're in
    $fileName = if ($OU -match 'OU=Domain Controllers') { 'Domain Controllers.csv' } else { 'Computers.csv'}
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $myFilePath -ChildPath $fileName

    Write-Host "Getting computer info from OU '$OU'"
    # get a string array of the computernames found in the OU
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    # loop through this array to get the properties you want for 
    # each computer and store that as objects in the $result variable
    $result = foreach($machine in $computers){
        Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machine | Select-Object -Property Name, Manufacturer, Model
    }
    Write-Host "Creating file '$filePath'"
    # save the CSV file to disk
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```